# How do i use spring mvc void controller method?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am reading spring framework reference. When i read [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.RC3/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-return-types). I found that spring mvc supports returning `void` types.And then i read some examples of using `void`.But these examples do not make me to understand when time to use `void`.Is there a better example of how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the referenced document:

*"... if the method handles the response itself (by writing the response content directly, declaring an argument of type ServletResponse / HttpServletResponse for that purpose) or if the view name is supposed to be implicitly determined through a RequestToViewNameTranslator (not declaring a response argument in the handler method signature)"*

There are two conditions listed.

1. If the method writes to the servletResponse directly.  In this case, there is nothing for spring to do; a return value of `void` tells spring "I got this" and it does nothing with the response.
2. If the view name can be determined vai a `RequestToViewNameTranslator`.  In this situation, spring knows the view to return based on the request, so no return value is required.

Comment: Thanks very much.After listening to your explanation, I can understand that.

Comment: If don't using template engine, `void` return type will be rarely used in actual applications.Right?

Comment: Yes.  I have only used void return type one time, when I wrote the content of the response myself.